# Is it illegal to use pictures of public figures to train a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, legal

I want to train a neural network with pictures of public figures (politicians, singers, etc), but I do not know if it's legal, I do not plan to show them in my project I only want to use them to train the neural network, can this cause legal problems?

Answer (score 7):

If you use any pictures you find online, you can use them as you wish: as long as you don't (re)publish them under your name. Also, if you really want to play safe, never *upload* them at all. Download them, use them, disregard them.

People can't proof you used certain pictures to train your network by looking at your network data.

And the 'big' companies out there, like Google, train their networks by using public photos.

And follow this chart:
[image]

As you are using it for a personal/educational project, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @sanandresm the point about re-publication is that someone likely holds the copyright on those images.  "Fair use" generally applies to creative content that is being excerpted, such as in a documentary or article.  In your case, it's not an issue, as you are not going to be re-publishing any of the content, and are merely using it in-house for research.  I have a good deal of experience with Intellectual Property law, but I am not an attorney, so if you have any outstanding concerns, I'd recommend asking this question on [Stack Law](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the country. In France, for example, you've got to have the agreement of the person. Doesn't matter whether he is the president, a singer or... me :)

**Edit:**

*Doesn't matter what for. Your image belongs to you. Otherwise he (me) can sue you for that and seek redress. Faces of persons are blurred in Google Map Street View. Here is [a link](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F32103), in french.*

About re-publication, you'll also have to have the agreement of the copyright holder.

Comment: Thanks for posting!  Here are some links regarding the recent changes:
 [DISPOSITIONS RELATIVES À LA LIBERTÉ DE CRÉATION ET À LA CRÉATION ARTISTIQUE](http://www.senat.fr/petite-loi-ameli/2015-2016/695.html)  ("PROVISIONS RELATING TO FREEDOM OF CREATION AND ARTISTIC CREATION").  [Article on TechDirt](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20160826/10092035354/france-passes-copyright-law-demanding-royalties-every-image-search-engines-index-online.shtml)